# Bootstrap div height settings breaks the grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the #intro div to have 90%  of window height. But when I set that in css it messes up the grid. When I minimize browser window "About me" section stacks and covers "What I do" part and three lower columns. However, when I remove height settings from css everthing works fine. Is there anyway to make row1 90% height and not break responsivness?

Here's my code with css: https://jsfiddle.net/yjakg7rL/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
  <title>Test resume page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!--Boostrap_css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!--Bootstrap_js-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--custom CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
  </head>

<body>

    <div id="intro" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row row1">

            <div class="col-md-4 column1">
                <img src="dva.jpg" class="rounded-circle img-responsive dva" alt="Gamer-grill" width="200" height="200">
                <h3>Name/surname</h3>
                <p>MEKA pilot. Top trash tier web dev</p>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-8 column2">
                <h3>About me</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet tempor ac, urna. Aenean congue risus commodo ligula sed nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus a, elementum eleifend, ligula. Vivamus eget tellus. Praesent quis mauris. Mauris interdum viverra. Ut id turpis nec ligula porttitor auctor, sapien eget augue quam eu risus. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque urna. Sed at sapien. Aenean tincidunt wisi augue nec urna felis, malesuada elit laoreet enim. Aliquam eget orci luctus et lacus et netus et lacus euismod orci luctus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc sapien. Morbi nisl dui quis wisi. Morbi fermentum suscipit id, libero. Morbi risus at nibh. Morbi ultrices.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>      



    <div class="container-fluid">

            <h3>What I do?</h3>
            <p> I'm eating ults. Omnomnomnomn. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>

    </div>

    <div class="row exp">

            <div class="col-lg"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet tempor ac, urna. Aenean congue risus commodo ligula sed nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus a, elementum eleifend, ligula. Vivamus eget tellus. Praesent quis mauris. Mauris interdum viverra. Ut id turpis nec ligula porttitor auctor, sapien eget augue quam eu risus. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque urna. Sed at sapien. Aenean tincidunt wisi augue nec urna felis, malesuada elit laoreet enim. Aliquam eget orci luctus et lacus et netus et lacus euismod orci luctus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc sapien. Morbi nisl dui quis wisi. Morbi fermentum suscipit id, libero. Morbi risus at nibh. Morbi ultrices.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet tempor ac, urna. Aenean congue risus commodo ligula sed nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus a, elementum eleifend, ligula. Vivamus eget tellus. Praesent quis mauris. Mauris interdum viverra. Ut id turpis nec ligula porttitor auctor, sapien eget augue quam eu risus. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque urna. Sed at sapien. Aenean tincidunt wisi augue nec urna felis, malesuada elit laoreet enim. Aliquam eget orci luctus et lacus et netus et lacus euismod orci luctus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc sapien. Morbi nisl dui quis wisi. Morbi fermentum suscipit id, libero. Morbi risus at nibh. Morbi ultrices.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet tempor ac, urna. Aenean congue risus commodo ligula sed nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus a, elementum eleifend, ligula. Vivamus eget tellus. Praesent quis mauris. Mauris interdum viverra. Ut id turpis nec ligula porttitor auctor, sapien eget augue quam eu risus. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque urna. Sed at sapien. Aenean tincidunt wisi augue nec urna felis, malesuada elit laoreet enim. Aliquam eget orci luctus et lacus et netus et lacus euismod orci luctus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc sapien. Morbi nisl dui quis wisi. Morbi fermentum suscipit id, libero. Morbi risus at nibh. Morbi ultrices.</p>
            </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has it's own classes and own set sizes, you'll need to modify there CSS classes to make appropriate changes.

Check out the documentation:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need 100% height? I think that is what is breaking your code. Also your bootstrap structure is not correct. Check out the code below.

```css
html, body {
 
 height: 100%;
}

#intro {
 
 height: 100%;
 
}

.row1 {
 
 height: inherit;

}

.column1 {
 
 background-color: #23af4b;
 
}

.column2 { 

 background-color: #eef2d0;
  
}


.exp {
 
 background-color: #eef2d0
 
}


.dva {
 
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
  <title>Test resume page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <!--Boostrap_css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!--Bootstrap_js-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <!--custom CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
  </head>
  
<body>

 <div id="intro" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row row1">
   
   <div class="col-md-4 column1">
    <img src="dva.jpg" class="rounded-circle img-responsive dva" alt="Gamer-grill" width="200" height="200">
    <h3>Name/surname</h3>
    <p>MEKA pilot. Top trash tier web dev</p>
   </div>
   
   
   <div class="col-md-8 column2">
    <h3>About me</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet tempor ac, urna. Aenean congue risus commodo ligula sed nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus a, elementum eleifend, ligula. Vivamus eget tellus. Praesent quis mauris. Mauris interdum viverra. Ut id turpis nec ligula porttitor auctor, sapien eget augue quam eu risus. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque urna. Sed at sapien. Aenean tincidunt wisi augue nec urna felis, malesuada elit laoreet enim. Aliquam eget orci luctus et lacus et netus et lacus euismod orci luctus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc sapien. Morbi nisl dui quis wisi. Morbi fermentum suscipit id, libero. Morbi risus at nibh. Morbi ultrices.</p>
   </div>
    
  </div>
 </div>  
  
 
  
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>What I do?</h3>
    <p> I'm eating ults. Omnomnomnomn. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
   </div>
  </div>
   

  
 <div class="row exp">
   
   <div class="col-lg"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet tempor ac, urna. Aenean congue risus commodo ligula sed nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus a, elementum eleifend, ligula. Vivamus eget tellus. Praesent quis mauris. Mauris interdum viverra. Ut id turpis nec ligula porttitor auctor, sapien eget augue quam eu risus. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque urna. Sed at sapien. Aenean tincidunt wisi augue nec urna felis, malesuada elit laoreet enim. Aliquam eget orci luctus et lacus et netus et lacus euismod orci luctus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc sapien. Morbi nisl dui quis wisi. Morbi fermentum suscipit id, libero. Morbi risus at nibh. Morbi ultrices.</p>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-lg"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet tempor ac, urna. Aenean congue risus commodo ligula sed nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus a, elementum eleifend, ligula. Vivamus eget tellus. Praesent quis mauris. Mauris interdum viverra. Ut id turpis nec ligula porttitor auctor, sapien eget augue quam eu risus. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque urna. Sed at sapien. Aenean tincidunt wisi augue nec urna felis, malesuada elit laoreet enim. Aliquam eget orci luctus et lacus et netus et lacus euismod orci luctus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc sapien. Morbi nisl dui quis wisi. Morbi fermentum suscipit id, libero. Morbi risus at nibh. Morbi ultrices.</p>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-lg"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet tempor ac, urna. Aenean congue risus commodo ligula sed nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus a, elementum eleifend, ligula. Vivamus eget tellus. Praesent quis mauris. Mauris interdum viverra. Ut id turpis nec ligula porttitor auctor, sapien eget augue quam eu risus. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque urna. Sed at sapien. Aenean tincidunt wisi augue nec urna felis, malesuada elit laoreet enim. Aliquam eget orci luctus et lacus et netus et lacus euismod orci luctus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc sapien. Morbi nisl dui quis wisi. Morbi fermentum suscipit id, libero. Morbi risus at nibh. Morbi ultrices.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
  
 </div>

 
</body>
</html>
```